# For $n \ge 3$, is $\mathbb R^n \setminus A$ simply connected for any countable set $A$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

This [Prove that $\mathbb R ^n $ without a finite number of points is simply connected for $n\geq 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186956/prove-that-mathbb-r-n-without-a-finite-number-of-points-is-simply-connected)  shows that $\mathbb R^n$ minus a finite set is simply connected for $n \ge 3$. I know that $\mathbb R^n$ minus a countable set is path connected.

My question is: Is $\mathbb R^n$ minus a countable set simply connected i.e. has trivial fundamental group , for $n \ge 3$ ?

Comment: Do you know whether $\Bbb R^3 \setminus\Bbb Q^3$ is simply connected?