# Explicit retraction of $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus $k$ points to wedge sum of $k$ copies of $S^{(n-1)}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, retraction

In proving $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus finitely many points is simply connected for $n\geq 3$, we use the fact above. This is intuitively very much clear but it would be very helpful if someone can help me to find the explicit retraction map. I couldn't able to find the map anywhere . Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of how to do it for a single puncture? The case of multiple punctures is similar, you just have to pick a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not co-linear with two of the punctures and then 'section off' $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that each partition contains exactly one puncture. Then, do the exact same procedure as for a single puncture (where you make sure the spheres you're retracting onto all have a point at the new point you've picked out), except now you need to make sure that the boundaries between partitions are all retracted onto the new point you've picked out.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186956/prove-that-mathbb-r-n-without-a-finite-number-of-points-is-simply-connected . See a few of the answers here.